# Crop/ forest/grass classification in Erdas

Tags: classification, landsat, erdas-imagine, clip

I am trying to calculate crop land, forest and grass land  to check the irrigation potential during the period from Landsat 8 image using supervised classification in ERDAS. I am finding difficult to differentiate the crop, grass and forest land.

Comment: What region are you interested in?

Comment: I think you might have to post some kind of sample that you are using for the labelled classes. The question is a bit too abstract as it stands.

Comment: If you are using supervised learning to differentiate between land covers, you might want to use "temporal NDVI". It is used for crop classification, and data is available in google